# How to evaluate a variable to access its runtime value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Ok, I don't know how to actually ask this question without showing it. (Also explains why I can't figure out how to search for it on Google.)

Given the following like of code:

`dijit.byId('leftNavigationPane').onLoad = function(){setSecondaryNav(url.secondaryNavId);};`

I want the variable `url.secondaryNavId` to be evaluated, so what I really want is it to be treated something like this:

`dijit.byId('leftNavigationPane').onLoad = function(){ setSecondaryNav('item1'); };`

I am sure there is probably a better way to do this, so feel free to suggest something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `eval`!

You can use a [self-invoking function](http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/) and [closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml) as follows:

```
dijit.byId('leftNavigationPane').onLoad = function(id){
    return function(){ setSecondaryNav(id); };
}(url.secondaryNavId);
```

This will execute the outer anonymous function immediately (at runtime), passing the `url.secondaryNavId` parameter, which will then create a closure that the inner anonymous function will use (so `id` will always contain the assignment-time value of the `url.secondaryNavId` property).

Comment: Thank You!  Javascript is still a mystery to me at times.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand these as much until recently, either.

Answer (score -1):

There is the JavaScript eval() function.